# Why is this line of JavaScript showing in the wrong spot?

Tags: javascript, debugging

I am building a website that has some parallax on the site. Below is what the console says is in the javascript file. I keep getting cannot read data destroy property, because the program has nothing to delete. The picture at the bottom is what I wrote vs what showed up? This is bootstrap studio and I was wondering if anyone has had this problem before?

```
window.addEventListener("resize", colReset);
let col = document.querySelectorAll(".col-xxl-6");
function colReset() {
window.matchMedia("(min-width: 992px)").matches ? VanillaTilt.init(col, {
    max: 15,
    speed: 400,
    perspective: 750,
    scale: 1.005
}) : col.vanillaTilt.destroy()
}
VanillaTilt.init(col, {
max: 15,
speed: 400,
perspective: 750,
scale: 1.005
});
```

[image: What I wrote vs what showed]

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting